# Playwright stopped seeing 'test' command

Tags: javascript, playwright-test

I'm using Visual Studio Code. From its console I'm trying to run

```
npx playwright test
```

but this error is thrown at me

```
error: unknown command 'test'. See 'npx playwright --help'.
```

I'm also using Playwright extension, it shows a special 'play' icon right in your code. And this 'play' icon works, i.e. the code runs, the browser opens, etc. But the npx playwright test command does not for some reason.

I've checked the directory, I'm in the right one: seva on MacBook-Air-Vsevolod.local in ~/Playwright

My package file:

```
{
  "name": "playwright",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.27.1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas what could've gone wrong?

Comment: What actually helped: npm init playwright@latest -- the reinstallation.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! I would recommend making an answer to your own question with your solution, and then coming back a couple days later to mark as accepted (2 day rule for own answer). That way people quickly know that your problem was indeed solved and it shows up accordingly in searches/lists.